# typescript: filter union type to members with a field present

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have a discriminated union type where a non-discriminant field appears on multiple members:

```js
interface Foo {
  type: 'foo';
  foo: string;
}

interface OptionalFoo {
  type: 'optionalfoo';
  foo?: string;
}

interface RequiredNullableFoo {
  type: 'requirednullable';
  foo: string | null | undefined;
}

interface Bar {
  type: 'bar';
  bar: string;
}

type All = Foo | OptionalFoo | RequiredNullableFoo | Bar;
```

I would like to define a type that can create a new type from this:

```js
type Foos = UnionMembersWithField<All, 'foo'>;
// Foos = Foo | OptionalFoo | RequiredNullableFoo;
```

I have a few promising attempts at defining `UnionMembersWithField`, but none works completely:

```js
// Utility type: `keyof All` is `'type'`, because it is the only field in common,
// but we want to accept any field from any union type.
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;

// This definition yields `Foo | RequiredNullableFoo` and drops `OptionalFoo`.
type UnionMembersWithField<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = T extends Record<K, any> ? T : never;

// This definition does not compile due to TS1170, but seems like the best expression of intent.
type UnionMembersWithField<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = T extends { [K]?: any } ? T : never;

// This definition yields `never`...
type UnionMembersWithField<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = Required<T> extends Record<K, any> ? T : never;

// ...which is surprising, because redefining it with a helper `DiscriminateUnion` type yields
// `Required<Foo> | Required<OptionalFoo> | Required<RequiredNullableFoo>`
type DiscriminateUnion<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> = T extends Record<K, V> ? T : never;
type UnionMembersWithField<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = DiscriminateUnion<Required<T>, K, any>;
```

The rest of my attempts variously did nothing (i.e. the output type was the same as the input type) or degenerated to `never`.

Given that `All['foo']` is `any` (since Typescript doesn't give a good type if all union members don't have the specified field), I'm not even sure that such a type is possible.

Comment: Have you looked into ts-toolbelt already: https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/ ? It creates types for most advanced use cases out-of-the-box inculding union types and merging multiple union types.

Comment: `type UnionMembersWithField<T, S> = T extends (infer A | infer B) ? (S extends keyof A ? A : never) |  (S extends keyof B ? B : never) : T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
type UnionMembersWithField<U, F> = 
  U extends U           // distribute U over the conditional
    ? F extends keyof U // check if the field F is in keyof U
      ? U
      : never
    : never

type Foos = UnionMembersWithField<All, 'foo'>;
// Foos = Foo | OptionalFoo | RequiredNullableFoo;
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=14#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyyYAngA4QBcyA5DJjQNwFH3rUDOYUoA5s-gC%20BAqEixEKAPJkwwdCDgAbDFjyFi5KrXSz5ipWyYtkbAPydufAcPyjw0eEmQAlCAEcArsCgQAJgBynkpKcABGShCqOCakFNQ0vl4%20-iDBoREQxhpsljwgvMgAPshpIcXIniB%20EDCg-jYi%20GKOksgAQnBQMRpx2jRhXdlEg1B51gS2BH3IAILlALxomBUycgrK0SVuyb6B6eGRWx1dAk0zAKog%20gCyEAC2YdAcAOrAYAAWqMAQSn4APBcADRoAB8yCWF2QEAAHpBqhxkBcTGY0NC4RAEcgANYQEjoGBIkxEVHIjREaggCAAN2gJkpNLpdmZM1UiMh1wUd0ezzen2%20vwB8yUILoDFBAgA9JLluh2bLVnoNioVtsPN49kEQocophGEA)

Comment: Ah, that's what `T extends T` means. (I had copied `KeysOfUnion` from elsewhere and wasn't sure why it worked.) That's a good trick to keep in my back pocket.

Comment: This is rad. Is there an elegant way to allow for multiple keys in the filter? e.g. `UnionMembersWithField<All, 'foo' | 'bar'>`, where both `foo` and `bar` must be present?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
type KeysOfUnion<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type UnionMembersWithField<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = Exclude<T, Required<Exclude<T, Pick<Required<T>, K>>>>
```

Let's dive into it a bit.
Let's start with this:

`type UnionMembersWithField<T, K extends KeysOfUnion<T>> = Exclude<T,Exclude<T, Pick<T, K>>>`:

- We're picking the `key` out of every type
- and then we're excluding those types from the union
- this will leave us with the complementary of what we want
- so we exclude once more

This will not take into account optional types, so we add `Required` to end up with the final version.

Here a playground showcasing [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnJgCeADhAFzIDkMmVA3PsrepQM5hSgDmjAvrlyhIsRCgDyJMMHQg4AGwxY8BYmUpV0UmXPksGTFgH52nHv0HDo8JMgBKEAI4BXYFAgATAHLP58uABG8hBKOExqFNTuLm6eIL7+QRAGBCymXCDcyAA+yPF+OcjOIB4QMKCeFkLg1mLIAEJwUGGqpJFUAU0pyJ1Q6ea4ArgRyACCBQC8aJiFktKyCqG5DjHu3gmBwUsNTYzDbcgA0hBEbOIwAKogOgA8ACoAfMhTd8gQAB6QJWzIr0bIAGsTugYL9kJQQBAAG7QRgjK46ACyEAAtgFoGwAOrAMAAC1QwAg8g89wANEc3p8IN8jiczpdrrJ7g8nlMAKLvBDyZylMn2JyuNY3DlcnkQPkABWACABNxWgs8zPJhxZLMEIyUPymCNkyLRGOxeIJRJJ43k5JodAejCAA).

Comment: There's an interesting sleight of hand here: `Required<Exclude<T, Pick<Required<T>, K>>>` results in `Required<OptionalFoo> | Required<Bar>`, so it isn't quite what I was expecting for "complement". But of course, `OptionalFoo` is not assignable to `Required<OptionalFoo>`, so the latter is effectively ignored in the outermost `Exclude`. Unfortunately, that optional/required juggling makes this less robust: if `Bar.bar` is made `?`-optional, the result erroneously includes `Bar`.